# Adding site URL to site title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

Sorry for how simple this must be.

I'm having trouble linking the site title in my Wordpress theme to the site URL.

This is my code:

```
    <h1><img id="logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name').$tagline; ?>" /></h1>
```

Can someone help me link this to the site URL? I need to create something I can add "text-decoration: none;" to.

Thanks

Comment: What HTML this code produces? What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1>
    <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">
        <img id="logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name').$tagline; ?>" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

That easy!

**edit**

Add it also to the text-only header:

```
<h1 id="page-title">
    <a href="/" style="text-decoration:none">
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, but for some reason this just doesn't add a link to the site title. I can't figure it out. It looks straightforward even to me.

Comment: Do you have an example page to share?

Comment: Your code is in the header.php. I tried Chafik's also. But something seems to override it, as the title won't link.

Comment: It seems you are modifying the wrong file, then. Are you modifying wp-blog-header.php in your template folder?

Comment: It's a very simple theme. Only a header.php file. Here's a pastebin of the whole header.php file, with your code added. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Take out the entire file and make sure you're editing the right file. I mean, rename the file to `backupfjkaslfdsa.php` or something. Refresh, check that you're editing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Joe. Your code is perfect. I'm an idiot. The child theme, not the main theme, was activated, and it included a header.php file. Put your edits in there, and it's fine. I forgot the child theme was on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>
    <a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>">
        <img id="logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name') . $tagline; ?>" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

Documentation : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url